# how to read and get data from txt file using golang

Tags: go

I have a txt file , In this file I need only int value , how can I get this value  ?

txt file -
Profit = 10 at the Time of ->04-06-2021 20:21:59

I am getting this file by using this code ..!

```
    func Profit() string {
    TargetClosePrice := 110
    ontickerPrice := 100
    Time := time.Now()
    totalProfit := TargetClosePrice - ontickerPrice
    str := strconv.Itoa(totalProfit)
    value := `Profit = ` + str + ` at the Time of ->` + Time.Format("01-02-2006 15:04:05") + "\n"

    data, err := os.OpenFile("Profit.txt", os.O_APPEND, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("whoops", err)
    }
    io.Copy(data, strings.NewReader(value))
    return str
}
```

but now I need only 10 from txt file..? how can I get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "fmt"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   f, e := os.Open("Profit.txt")
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   s := bufio.NewScanner(f)
   for s.Scan() {
      var n int
      fmt.Sscanf(s.Text(), "Profit = %v", &n)
      fmt.Println(n)
   }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Scanf

Comment: thank's ..! can you tell me how can I get sum of all the data  @StevenPenny